# Json data to CSV file format using Python

Tags: python, json, django, csv, django-rest-framework

I have JSON data I want to convert to a CSV file. How can I do this with Python?

Below, is the json structure.

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "matter_id": 1,
            "billing_clientId": 1,
            "billing_contactID": 1,
            "branch_code": "8032FHDSL",
            "category": "sadsaddda",
        }
    ]
}
```

what i tried below, but it's throw me ValueError: "Invalid file path or buffer object type: <class 'collections.OrderedDict'> "

```
for record in serializer.data:
    import pandas as pd
    import json
    df = pd.read_json(record)
    print('df----->', df)
    df.to_csv("/home/satyajitbarik/test.csv", index = None)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
import json

json_data = {
    "data": [
        {
            "matter_id": 1,
            "billing_clientId": 1,
            "billing_contactID": 1,
            "branch_code": "8032FHDSL",
            "category": "sadsaddda",
        }
    ]
}

data = json_data['data'][0]

output_file = open('output_file.csv', 'w')


#This would be "for key, value in data.iteritems():" in python 2
for key, value in data.items():
    output_file.write(str(key) + '; ' + str(value) + '\n')

output_file.close()
```

Note: The dictionary "data" should be an OrderedDict in python 3.5 and below

Comment: In this line, `data = json_data['data'][0]`  i'm getting TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: Could this be a typo? It works completely fine on my machine. I am using Python 3.9.0

Comment: This also works on my machine when pass the static data is `json_data`, when i make dynamic `json_data=serializer.data` then it's throwing me this error.

Comment: The whole code is in this link---> https://pastebin.com/bPhEKt07

Comment: I believe this means that the JSON file "serializer.data" is formatted differenty then the example data. After you get the JSON file try printing it to the console and then formatting this line accordingly

Comment: After print the "serializer.data" in console tab, then it's printing this --> `[OrderedDict([('matter_id', 1), ('billing_clientId', 1), ('billing_contactID', 1), ('branch_code', '8032FHDSL')])]`

Comment: I see what the problem is. Try adding the following snippet before the error causing line:

Comment: Sorry... I did not understand.

Comment: nvm, just replace this error causing line with: ```data = json_data[0]```

Comment: Hey..... It's printing the first object in the csv file....if i have multiple object in the data then  i want all the multiple object should be in the csv file.

Comment: do you mean that there are multiple OrderedDicts in the list. If so that line should be ```json_data = {}\njson_data.update(i) for i in data```

Comment: nvm, it's throwing SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character

Comment: i just pus the \n to represent a new line since i cnat put a newline in a comment

Answer (score 1):

First of all imports should be done outside the for loop not inside. Putting the imports within a function will cause calls to that function to take longer.

```
import json
import csv

json_data = {
    "data": [
        {
            "matter_id": 1,
            "billing_clientId": 1,
            "billing_contactID": 1,
            "branch_code": "8032FHDSL",
            "category": "sadsaddda",
        }
    ]
}

# with open('data.json') as json_file:
#     data = json.load(json_data)

some_data = json_data['data']

data_file = open('data_file.csv', 'w')

csv_writer = csv.writer(data_file)
count = 0
 
for row in some_data:
    if count == 0:
 
        # Writing headers of CSV file
        header = row.keys()
        csv_writer.writerow(header)
        count += 1
 
    # Writing data of CSV file
    csv_writer.writerow(row.values())
 
data_file.close()
```

Comment: While it's true that the imports should be moved to the top, the reason is not that "for every iteration your code would import packages again which could be hard on your memory."

Comment: Thanks for the correction. @juanpa.arrivillaga is the reason valid now ?